# Guage of wire from main disconnect at shop under ground 100' to house a NATO supply 220 hot tub

Tags: electrical

What gauge of wire do I need to run from main electrical disconnect and Shop 100 feet Underground 2 disconnect panel in house that will also Supply a hot tub 220 volt?

Comment: NATO? I don't think you are talking about [NATO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO) so please explain. How much power does the hot tub need (Watts or VA)? What is the current configuration of panels - main vs. sub, shop vs. house?

Comment: How is the house currently fed with power?